# what's the difference between QVTo and QVTr transformation?

Tags: mde, qvt

I want to do a model to model transformation, from a model based on Java metamodel to a model based on C++ metamodel.
I did some research and I found that QVT allow a bidirectional transformation but there is two types of QVT and I don't understand the difference between them, who is the more suitable for my project QVTo or QVTr ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is the nature of the languages, QVTr is declarative and QVTo is imperative. In this particular case, another important factor when taking your decision is current tool support. A mature and stable implementation of QVTo is part of the Eclipse Modeling Project. For QVTr current support is more limited. There is an ongoing development available as part of the Eclipse Modeling Project too.

In the mean time I would recommend you to consider alternatives as such as Epsilon, which does not only provide a transformation language (ETL) but also other languages to work with models. You can find more information about them here: [Eclipse MMT Projects](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mmt)